# Разработка БД для учета катриджей

Tags: база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста есть две сущности

Информация о принтере

```
Принтер
-------
Id 
Название
Модель
```

Информация о картриджах

```
Катридж
-------
Id
Модель
Цвет 
Id принтера
```

Какая у них должна быть связь? И верно ли `ID` принтера должно быть в сущности картриджи? или наоборот? `IDкартридж` в сущности `принтеры`?

Comment: Обычно модель картриджа, если не обрезать символы, однозначно определяет цвет - так что поле цвета в таблице картриджей не нужно... Обычно модель картриджа подходит для нескольких принтеров, а принтер использует несколько моделей картриджей - так что связь M:N и необходима связующая таблица.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно один картридж подходит к нескольким принтерам. Но:

- производитель может сделать расширенный модельный ряд картриджей, например, "обычные" и "повышенной емкости", или с особыми чернилами для особой бумаги, и т. д.
- у цветных принтеров картриджи для каждого цвета могут быть отдельными

Так что я бы на всякий случай сделал связь многие-ко-многим. Соответственно, у вас будут сущности:

Картридж:

```
Катридж
-------
Id
Модель
Цвет
```

Принтер:

```
Принтер
-------
Id 
Название
Модель
```

"Таблица соответствия моделей":

```
Соответствие моделей
--------------------
ID картриджа
ID принтера
```

Comment: а скажите пожалуйста есть ли смысл цвета катриджей выносить в отдельную таблицу

Comment: В принципе (с точки зрения нормализации) смысл есть, но на практике может оказаться излишней детализацией.

Comment: А подскажите еще пожалуйста необходимо иметь информацию о том что прибыли заправленые картриджи и что имеются на складе не заправленые катриджи как лучше эти сущности назвать?

Comment: А точно нужна отдельная сущность? Здесь, как мне кажется, достаточно будет одного поля с типом boolean (если ваша СУБД поддерживает) или числовое: 1 - "заправленный картридж", 0 - "пустой картридж".

Comment: т.е. в сущность Катридж вы предлагаете сделать поле СТАТУС?

Comment: Ну да, что-то вроде того.

Comment: Необходимо что бы система отслеживала сколько заправленых катреджей сколько пустых. Так как предприятие отдает на заправку катриджи то и это тоже нужно отслеживать сколько отдали сколько прибыло.

Comment: У предприятия например 15 катриджей. Система как только понимает что осталась 5 катриджей бьет тревогу.)

Comment: Ну так все просто - `select count(*) from cartridge where is_empty = 1`. Как только больше пяти, так бейте тревогу.

Comment: "сколько отдали сколько прибыло" - так это же совсем другое дело, отдельная сущность, не "картридж", а что-то вроде "заказа" или "закупки".

Comment: ну тогда две разных сущности делать или все в одной?  ну например "заказ" где будит ID катриджа и дата принятия и "отправка" где будит id катриджа и дата отправки? или все в одну сущность? как правильно то?

Comment: и еще не понятно как катриджи и принтеры будут "вязаться" друг с другом в системе? т.е. как понять что к такому то принтеру нужен вот такой катридж? если не трудно напишите сущности? не совсем понятно(

Comment: "как правильно то" - совсем правильно вот как: поскольку мы уже далеко ушли от стартового вопроса, давайте вы еще раз подумаете и сформулируете вопрос заново целиком (или создадите новый). Потому что если в каждом комментарии добавлять по одному новому требованию, это не закончится никогда. "и еще не понятно как катриджи и принтеры будут "вязаться" друг с другом в системе?" - ну так вроде мой ответ как раз про это был. Попробую подробнее расписать.